# Adding a JLabel to a JPanel creates a NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel, jlabel

Sorry to ask such a dumb question, but I can't figure out why this is crashing. I'm just trying to add a JLabel on top of my JPanel. The JLabel simply is there to display an image. I'm getting a NullPointerException.

(prediction: this is going to wind up being one of those "duh" moments.)

```
public JDlgTable() {
        ImageIcon myImg = new ImageIcon("image.png");
        JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(myImg);        
        myPanel.add(myLabel);   <-- error happens here
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is `JPanel myPanel = new JPanel()`? If that's not it, post the error and the stack trace.

Comment: The only possible NPE on that line is when `myPanel` would be `null`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Wow, was that stupid. I hadn't called my initialization function, so there were not controls anywhere on my form. What a colossal idiot. Thanks for the help. Sorry to be an idiot.

Comment: I think its better to contain bad words on a public place. Even if you say them to yourself.